# Alert Dialog Builder null pointer exception

Tags: exception, pointers, dialog, null, alert

currently stuck at this issue for 2 days.

I am trying to show a Alert Dialogue if I get an error but it keeps crashing on this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Login.this);
```

I have tried

getApplicationContext() and getBaseContext() as well but it does not help.

Some code:

Code to trigger to login

```
private OnClickListener loginBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Login Button");

        //Pass user input to webservice

        SoapHandler soapHandler = new SoapHandler();
        //if token  invalid/expire, go back to login screen.
        soapHandler.loginWS(type, loginId, password);


    }
};

//******************** Main Webservice Handler
    public  void callSoapService(final String action, final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) {
        resultHandler = new ResultHandler();
        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                try {

                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", "=====================Sending Webservice================");
                    androidHttpTransport.call(action, envelope);

                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", "*************** Response from Webservice ***************");
                    Object resp = envelope.getResponse();
                    String res = (resp != null ? resp.toString() : "-1;No response found.");
                    webservice_result = res;
                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", webservice_result);

                    threadMsg(webservice_result);

                }

                catch (Exception ex){
                    error = ex.getClass().toString();
                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", error);

                }   
            }
            private void threadMsg(String msg) {
                if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
                    Message msgObj = ResultHandler.handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString(action, msg);
                    msgObj.setData(b);

                    ResultHandler.handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
                }

                else{
                    //Server unreachable/network issue
                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Server unreachable or network Issue");
                }
            }
        });

        //start new thread  to send webservice
        background.start();     
    }
```

Finally code to handle result

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        action = SoapHandler.action;
        String webservice_result = msg.getData().getString(action);

        if ((null != webservice_result)) {

            // ALERT MESSAGE
            // if Server is online, return result to respective method

            //******************************* return result to Login activity
            if(action.equals("Login")){
                Login login = new Login();
                login.isLoginSuccess(webservice_result);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            // ALERT MESSAGE
            //if Server cannot be reached
            Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Server down");

        }   

    }
```

Place to trigger Alert Dialog:

```
public void isLoginSuccess(String result)
{
    if (result.startsWith("0")) {
        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "LOGIN OK");
    }

    else{

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Error logs:

```
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at com.example.mym1revamp.Login.isLoginSuccess(Login.java:113)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at com.example.mym1revamp.Soap.ResultHandler$1.handleMessage(ResultHandler.java:27)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-03 16:47:20.950: E/AndroidRuntime(15934):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Added Login Class:

```
public class Login extends Slider {

/*private String ID_TYPE = 0;
private String ID = "";
private String MobileNumber = "";*/

//public final Context context = this;
private Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    getSlidingMenu(this);
    buttonControls();


}

public void buttonControls(){
    findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(loginBtnClickListener);
    //findViewById(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener(dafugBtnClickListener);
}

private OnClickListener dafugBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Login Button");

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Login.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    Login.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

    }
};


private OnClickListener loginBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Login Button");

        //Pass user input to webservice
        //String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.auth_type_title);
        //String authType = items[(Integer)((TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_idtype_title_view)).getTag()]; 
        //String authId = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_auth_id)).getText().toString().toUpperCase();
        //String mobileNo = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_mobile_no)).getText().toString();

        String authType = 
        String authId = 
        String mobileNo = 

        //SoapHandler soapHandler = SoapHandler.getInstance();
        SoapHandler soapHandler = new SoapHandler();
        //if token  invalid/expire, go back to login screen.
        soapHandler.loginWS(authType, authId, mobileNo);


    }
};

public void isLoginSuccess(String result)
{
    Log.d("APP_STATUS", "IS LOGIN SUCCESS?");
    if (result.startsWith("0")) {
        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "LOGIN OK");
    }

    else{

        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "Login Button");

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Login.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    Login.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
    }
}



//switch to remember login credentials
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "ON");
    } else {
        Log.d("APP_STATUS", "OFF");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Login is a non activity class? If so you will need the activity context. Pass the activity context to the non activity class constructor and use the same.

Comment: hi there my login is a activity class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
public void isLoginSuccess(final String result) {

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (result.startsWith("0")) {
                    Log.d("APP_STATUS", "LOGIN OK");
                }

                else {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: As your logcat says you are passing wrong context or null context

Comment: i tried using 


AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)

still crashing :(

Comment: @user2742339 is Login a non activity class. Does it extend activity> if its a activity class you are doing this  `Login login = new Login()` which is wrong. activity is started by `startActivity`.

Comment: @user2742339 post your `Login` class full.

Comment: added Login class to the question

Comment: @user2742339 activity is started by `startActivity` and you need to extend activity. what is Slider? Do not create an instance of your activity class. start activity Login using `startActivity`. Or make your Login class non activity class/utility class.